# making vectors of an object independent of each other

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, shared-ptr, copy-constructor

I have a question regarding vectors, shared_ptr, and copy c'tors.

```
class Character 
{
     int health;//and more stuff that aren't important for the sake of this question
     //more code...
}

class Game 
{
     int size;
     vector<shared_ptr<Character>> board;
}
```

When I do this:

```
Game game1 = (53,...)//say that I gave proper values for game1 to be constructed.
Game game2 = game1;
```

What would be the vector that's in `game2`? Does the vector in `game2` have the same address as the vector in `game1`? Or is it a vector with a different address but the same contents?

Moreover, if the answer to my question is that they're the same vector (meaning they have the same address), how can I make them independent of each other? What I want is for both vectors to have the same contents but different addresses!

If anyone is confused by what I mean with contents: it's the shared_ptrs inside the vector

Comment: "What would be the vector that's in game2?" Just try it?

Comment: `Game game2 = game1;` will indeed create a copy of `game1` but since `board` is a vector of `std::shared_ptr<character>` the addresses it refers to still remains intact, so if you try to access the shared pointer, you will be accessing the same location. In the first place, why are you even using `vector<shared_ptr<character>>`, why not just do `vector<character>`?

Comment: I'm gonna go out on a limb and say you ask this question because you used `shared_ptr` as a "best practice" and then saw the two games affecting each other. That in turn made you wonder how come. The actual answer to this is that you should not be using `shared_ptr` here, because you don't seem to really want to share any data between instances of `Game`.

Comment: @Ruks doing {vector<character>} will actually cause some problems, as there are a bunch of classes that inherit from Character and add some inner values to those speceific classes, therefore I'm using shared_ptr.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica it's sort of true that I'm using shared_ptr as best practice, if it were up to me personally I would actually use unique_ptr as it is more suitable for my situation but I'm forced by my professor to use shared_ptr :(.

Comment: You have several objects of type 'Character'. You want to store their addresses (not the whole objects) in several vectors, such that two vectors may store the same addresses. Those vectors start at different RAM positions, this is, they have different address, just because they have different names or belong to different classes or to different instances of the same class (being the vector a not-static one). But the contents are the same: addresses of 'Character' objects. These addresses are best stored in 'shared_ptr'

Comment: You should still use `std::unique_ptr`. That way the compiler will force you to implement copying. Then once you have that, you can replace the smart pointer type.  It will be way harder to catch mistakes if your code implicitly does the wrong thing without telling you, as it does now. And you have my sympathies for having that professor teach you. The pedagogical effect is wrong here IMO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

game2 will contain copy of vector in game1. It will basically copy all its `std::shared_ptr`.

However, copy of `std::shared_ptr` means only, that internal ref count will be incremented, object which it points to will be the same as in the original `std::shared_ptr`.

Example:

```
std::shared_ptr<Character> ptr1 = std::make_shared<Character>();
std::shared_ptr<Character> ptr2 = ptr1; // Copy of ptr1, however ptr2 points to same object as ptr1
```

EDIT:
Thus, `std::vector` addresses will be different, which means that also `std::shared_ptr` addresses will be different. Only, `Character` objects in game1 and game2 will have same addresses.

Comment: I'm aware of the fact that, my question is if the address for the board vector in game2 is the same address as the address for board vector in game1

Comment: Addresses of vectors will be different. Only Character objects will have same addresses.